# Transform a list in a data structure

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to know it it's possible to create a function that transforms this list :

```
['music\n', ' extension=mp3\n', '\n', 'reports/INFOB131\n', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf\n', ' name_contains=INFOB131\n', ' max_size=100000\n', '\n', 'reports/INFOB132\n', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf\n', ' name_contains=INFOB132\n', ' max_size=100000\n', '\n', 'games\n', ' name_contains=SC2,Wesnoth\n', '\n', 'pictures/Namur\n', ' extension=jpeg\n', ' min_size=5000000\n', ' name_contains=cercle\n', '\n', 'pictures/autres\n', ' extension=jpeg\n', ' min_size=5000000']
```

Which has been gotten from a text file using the readlines() functions.

Into a data structure like this one :

```
data_config = [{'music' : {'extension':'mp3'}}, {'reports/INFOB131': {'extension': ['doc', 'docx','pdf'], 'name_contains':'INFOB131', 'max_size':100000}}, {'reports/INFOB132': {'extension': ['doc', 'docx','pdf'], 'name_contains':'INFOB132', 'max_size':100000}}]
```

I started to clean the list by those processes :

```
new_lines = []
for i in lines :
  new_lines.append(str.strip(i, '\n'))

for i in new_lines:
  if i == '':
    new_lines.remove(i)
```

And I obtained this :

```
['music', ' extension=mp3', 'reports/INFOB131', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB131', ' max_size=100000', 'reports/INFOB132', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB132', ' max_size=100000', 'games', ' name_contains=SC2,Wesnoth', 'pictures/Namur', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000', ' name_contains=cercle', 'pictures/autres', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000']
```

Next, I have the idea to do something like this in theory:

create a function that will browse in the list and if "=" is not in the element of the list, this will be defined as the variable k. else, the element of the list will be added to a list named pre_list and until another element without "=" in it is not encountered, this pre_list is updated and then when a new element with "=" in it is encountered a dictionary containig the variable key as a list and the pre_list is the element assigned to this key.

```
 def my_function(list_in_question, my_config_list =[]):
 """ """
 for i in list_in_question :

    #it misses the first if for the situation in which the function stops 
    if not '=' in i:
        my_config_list.append({key:pre_list})
        i = key
        pre_dict = {key:{}}

    else:
        pre_dict[key][i.split('=')[0]] = i.split('=')[1]

        return myfunction(list_in_question[list_in_question.index(i):])
```

I'd like to create it in a recursive way. I have issues. One of them is that I don't know how I would stop it...

Comment: yes, it is posibble. What did you try ?

Comment: put in question code which you tried, and full error messages (Traceback) if you get any error.

Comment: The only code I could think of was the one I put down in the answer section, I couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: put code in answer - show what did you try. It is very important in question. if you didn't show code then you will downvoted because people will think that you are too lazy to do anything.

Comment: BTW: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In answer ? We are talking of the comment section, right ?

Comment: edit **question** and put code.

Comment: I think you should put original text from file - it will show its structure and better explain it. Maybe it uses some popular format (like YAML) and it can be readed with existing module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was more complicated than I expected.
Now It is difficalt to explain all code.
It works with current data but I'm not sure if it will work with other data.

```
data = ['music\n', ' extension=mp3\n', '\n', 'reports/INFOB131\n', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf\n', ' name_contains=INFOB131\n', ' max_size=100000\n', '\n', 'reports/INFOB132\n', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf\n', ' name_contains=INFOB132\n', ' max_size=100000\n', '\n', 'games\n', ' name_contains=SC2,Wesnoth\n', '\n', 'pictures/Namur\n', ' extension=jpeg\n', ' min_size=5000000\n', ' name_contains=cercle\n', '\n', 'pictures/autres\n', ' extension=jpeg\n', ' min_size=5000000']

config_list_2 = []

# variable for dictionary
prev_ext = None
curr_ext = ''
prev_list = list()
prev_dict = dict()

for item in data:

    # remove spaces, tabs and '\n'
    item = item.strip()

    # create dictionary and sometimes new sublist 
    if not item:
        if (prev_ext is not None) and curr_ext != prev_ext:
            config_list_2.append(prev_list)
            prev_list = list()
        prev_list.append(prev_dict)
        prev_dict = dict()
        prev_ext = curr_ext
        curr_ext = ''

    # work only with elements `key=value`
    if '=' in item:

        # split `key=value`
        key, value = item.split('=')

        # if value has `,` then it is list of values
        if ',' in value:
            value = value.split(',')

        # if you get `extension then you have start new dictionary
        if key == 'extension':
            curr_ext = value

        # some values have to be converted to int()
        if key in ('max_size', 'min_size'):
            value = int(value)

        # add to current dictionary
        prev_dict[key] = value

# add last dictionary

if (prev_ext is not None) and curr_ext != prev_ext:
    config_list_2.append(prev_list)
    prev_list = list()
prev_list.append(prev_dict)

# add last sublist

config_list_2.append(prev_list)

# --- print result ---

print(config_list_2)

# --- compare with expected result --

expected = [[{'extension' : 'mp3'}], [{'extension':['doc','docx', 'pdf'], 'name_contains':'INFOB131', 'max_size':100000}, {'extension':['doc','docx', 'pdf'], 'name_contains':'INFOB132', 'max_size':100000}],[{'name_contains':['SC2','Wesnoth']}],[{'extension':'jpeg', 'min_size':5000000, 'name_contains':'cercle'}, {'extension':'jpeg', 'min_size':5000000}]]

print(config_list_2 == expected) # True
```

Comment: Thank you, you were great help I'll try this and see if it's suitable for my homework ! Really thank you for your time !!!